# How do I utilise the OnUserAction method of the WalletAgent class using Windows Phone 8 Wallet?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-agent

I have created a Windows Phone 8 app that allows the adding of a PaymentInstrument to the wallet. I have also added a background agent and have managed to override the OnRefreshData method...

I can only find examples of the OnRefreshData method being used to keep PaymentInstruments updated. How do I utilise the OnUserAction method? I can see that it can be overridden, but I cannot work out how to invoke the event from the wallet.

For some context...

I want to change the card/account details held in the wallet, but I do not want to do this every time the wallet is accessed or refreshed, I want the user to be able to initiate the update with an action. I can see that it is possible to link into the app from the wallet, so I may fall back on this as a solution, but ideally I would like to use a background process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/52842cd6-35d4-49bf-af76-9338befbbecf/how-do-i-utilise-the-onuseraction-method-of-the-walletagent-class-using-windows-phone-8-wallet) in the Windows Phone Development forum, I received this answer:

> OnUserAction needs mobile operator support in order to use since the app will need access to the Secure Element on the device.

There is some more information about the Secure Element API and the use of OnUserAction [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.secureelement%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Essentially, control over the Secure Element API lies with the mobile operator:

> The use of the Secure Element API in an app requires a specific type of SIM card provisioned by a mobile operator on phones that run the app. If you are collaborating with a mobile operator on an app that uses mobile payments, contact the mobile operator for the information necessary to use the Secure Element API.